# Can somebody provide me with the $price per GHps in mining since the old CPU days til present pre-orders?

Tags: mining-hardware, hashpower, history

Can somebody provide me with the $price per GHps in mining since the old CPU days til present pre-orders?
I don't mean energy usage or price vs price of btc.. simply hardware costs relative to how fast they hash.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a good way of measuring that in the early days. When CPU mining was actually doable, people would just use hardware they had. It didn't necessarily "cost" them anything. Even with GPU mining it's hard to estimate GH/s/$ because these weren't *made* for mining.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison
it gives a large list of CPU and GPU hardware. It does not give MHS/$ for CPUs, because it is tricky to calculate. But you could estimate the value.

Actual preorder GHS/$ you can find at the mining dashboard:
http://mining.thegenesisblock.com/

Comment: I'm more looking for a historical evolution of the cost to hash..